# what is the equivalent of html onclick in javascript

Tags: android, plugins, cordova, include, call

Hi I create a phonegap plugin to print to a bluetooth printer.

I create a hello world demo app in order to call the plugin and print some text to the printer with the following code

```
<a href="#" class="btn enc" onclick="msgbox.show1('test');">print</a>
```

and everything works fine.

Then I try to include the same plugin inside my normal app but in this case I have to call the plugin from my main .js. So I call it like this

```
if ((i+1) == len){
     msgbox.show1('test');
     alert(print_entryseason);
}
```

But it does not happen anything...

Where am I wrong?

Comment: I haven't used phonegap ever, but I'm willing to bet that more information would help anyone able to answer this, for example, I have NO clue what i's value is, and what 'len' is, for all I know they are never equal, and that is why you're not seeing anything happen.

Comment: the alert works in the above code

Comment: Then the question is not clear, it says "But it does not happen anything", from what I can tell the alert doesn't happen (based on that comment). I suspect others reading this (who could actually answer your question) would appreciate some clarification.